# Unable to create the docker network inside of App Service in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to setup multi container application in Azure DevOps services. I have used "Azure Web App for Containers" task to run the application on App service with the support of docker compose. I have used "Run Services" part of Docker Compose Task and provided the docker-compose.yml file path.

When the deployment starts, the docker compose tries to create the docker network by adding alias in the prefix. I'm getting the parameter is incorrect. How to fix it?

[image]

**Log is not retrieving in App Service Console**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I did not guess wrong, you are using Hosted Windows agent?

Because this error message `HNS failed with error : The parameter is incorrect.` represents a known NAT network created limitation on **Windows**.

**Solution:**

Just change the agent used to **Ubuntu**, and it will run successfully.

[image]

---

You can see, it's **Succeed with Ubuntu agent:**

[image]

BUT **Failed with VS2017 Hosted agent:**

[image]

Comment: I've configured "Run Services from Docker Compose Task" in Release pipeline. How to change the hosted agent to Ubuntu?

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS, Just change it here. https://imgur.com/a/Z8B8t2k

Comment: Liang The site is not recheable

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS, Ohhh, sorry. I forgot this. Updating in my answer.

Comment: Liang, Yes It is working. Can we deploy multi container on App Service?

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS. Awesome!! Of course yes. Though I did not achieve this by myself, but I know Azure App Service support multi-container

Comment: Thanks Merline Liang. I was using App service for single container but for some reason the logs are not displaying in the Log section in App Service console. The error message shows as `Error in retrieving logs.`  Not sure what went wrong in App service. Can you help?

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS,  I owned by azure devops team, not too familiar with azure. But will try based on my known knowledge.  do you mean you could not retrieve log in azure portal?

Comment: @Merline Liang Yes. I have added the screenshot of the error in the question.

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS. I'm sorry. It out of my known. You may contact our [official community](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/community/). The engineer who work for azure will help you on troubleshooting.

Comment: Sure. Thanks @Merline Liang :)